# Best way to avoid duplicate code if two classes extending different class

Tags: java, android, code-duplication

I am working on an Android project and i am facing this situation.

I have 2 class :

```
class A extends B
{

openDoor(){
//impl
}

closeDoor(){
//impl
}

}

class X extends Y{

openDoor(){
//impl
}

closeDoor(){
//impl
}

}
```

Now if you observe the are two methods common in both the classes `openDoor()` and `closeDoor()`

what is the best way to avoid duplicate methods?

**My Approach**

```
class ContainingDuplicateMethods{

     openDoor(){
    //impl
    }

    closeDoor(){
    //impl
    }

    }
   }
```

Create a object of ContainingDuplicateMethods in both the class and call the methods, which we call it as **Strategy Pattern**,but is this the best solution? why because in large projects we cannot follow this approach and people say it not GOOD PRACTICE, in that case what approach do i need to follow ?

Please note that `class A and X` are already extending other classes and also i dont want to use static because - Static members are loaded into memory when the program execution starts and will be in memory until the program is terminated, say my code runs continuously for days or weeks and keeps on creating many number of objects using the static references so there might be a chance that we could run out of memory.

Comment: 1. use an abstract class.. put your common methods there... other classes which want to  use these methods can do it by extending the abstract class...
2. in case you are already extending another class, you have very little choice..

Comment: @TheLostMind yes but my class A and X are already extending the classes

Comment: then create a common utils class and make these methods as static. u can use these common methods by "UtilsClass.openDoor(). " in your other classes directly without inheritance...

Comment: I think you have to use use strategy pattern.. I dont see any other option here... I am not a big fan of static methods/fields :P

Comment: Static is not the way to go. See my answer.

Comment: @TimB please see my comment

Answer (score 18):

"Favour composition over inheritance" is a useful thing to remember.

Have a `Door` class with open and close. Include a `Door` as a member of both `A` and `B`.

Voila, job done.

So `A.getDoor().close()`. `B.getDoor().open()` etc.

If you need a common interface for both `A` and `B` (so you can use either somewhere) then create

```
interface HasDoor {
    Door getDoor();
}
```

Now `A` and `B` can extend any class you like and implement `HasDoor`. Any class requiring a door can accept a `HasDoor` (or just directly accept the `Door` object) and call open, close, etc.

No duplicated code, full flexibility.

If you need your `Door` to call methods back in `A` and `B` then create the `Door` class as abstract and implement it in `A` and `B` as an anonymous inner class. The abstract methods will be called from `Door` and then you can do whatever processing is needed in `A` and `B` when those methods are called.

For example class A becomes:

```
 class A implements HasDoor {
      private Door door = new Door() {
          @override void notifyDoorChanged(boolean closed) {
                // The door is telling us its been opened or closed
          }
      }

      @override
      public Door getDoor() {
           return door;
      }
 }
```

Where door is:

```
 public abstract class Door {
      boolean closed;
      abstract notifyDoorChanged();

      public void close() {
         closed = true;
         notifyDoorChanged(closed);
      }

      // etc
 }
```

Note that this is similar to the strategy pattern - but its not quite the same. The Strategy pattern has one master object and then you plug in multiple strategies (i.e. different forms of Door). This has one Door and multiple other objects using the same type of Door, although you could extend it to use the Strategy pattern and have multiple door implementations very easily.

Answer (score 3):

This is the implementation of the answer posted by Tim B.
It is a very flexible approach to go with. It is following the principles of object oriented reuse :

1. Identify that varies and separate them from what stays the same.
2. Program to an interface , not an implementation.
3. Favor object composition over inheritance.

   public class Main {

   ```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           X x = new X();
           A a = new A();
           x.getDoor().open();
           x.getDoor().close();
           a.getDoor().open();
           a.getDoor().close();
       }
   }


   interface HasDoor {
       Door getDoor();
   }

   interface Door {
       public void open();
       public void close();
   }

   class A extends B implements HasDoor {
   Door d;

   @Override
   public Door getDoor() {
       Door door = new Door() {
           public void open() {
               System.out.println("Open A's Door");
           }

           public void close() {
               System.out.println("Close A's Door");
           }
       };
       return door;
   }
   ```

   }

   class X extends Y implements HasDoor{
       Door d;

   ```
   @Override
   public Door getDoor() {
       Door door = new Door() {
           public void open() {
               System.out.println("Open X's Door");
           }

           public void close() {
               System.out.println("Close X's Door");
           }
       };
       return door;
   }
   ```

   }

   class B {}
   class Y {}

If you do not want to use HasDoor interface, you can declare constructors inside the class X and class A that initializes the Door instance.

Example ;

```
class X extends Y {
    Door d;
     public X() {
         d = new Door() {
            public void open() {
                System.out.println("Open X's Door");
            }

            public void close() {
                System.out.println("Close X's Door");
            }
        };

     }



}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this approach still has duplicated code according to op's problem. In Tim B's answer, Door is a abstract class that's why it can have concrete implementation for open() and close() methods. In your approach, Door is Interface. That's why class A and class X still has to provide concrete implementation for Door's open() and close() methods. These two methods are identically same as per op's question.

Answer (score 1):

so here your class a and class a has to follow same functions.
that is both classes have same functions.

since the classes already extended another class we can use interface

```
interface door
{
 openDoor(){
    }

    closeDoor(){
    }


}
```

both class a and x can implement the door interface.
[image]

A class can implement any number of interfaces but can extend only one class.

if implementation of class door is same  we can do like this

```
class Door
{
openDoor(){
impl//
    }

    closeDoor(){
impl//
    }


}
class A extends b
{
Door d=new Door();
d.opendoor();
d.closeDorr();


}
```

Comment: Yes but my implementation of openDoor() closeDoor() is also same, so creating an interface will again have dulpicate implementations

Comment: if implementation also same then write it inside a class.and in class a and X create an object of door class and access the close and open functions

Comment: ok, then where will i use this interface ? i am totally confused can you please elaborate

Comment: then no need of interface,just create a class door and implment that functions.then where ever you need that functons just create the object of that class and access it.in the case of validation we do like this create one class for validation and use this one in all other classes.

Comment: you mean creating an object of that class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create an abstract class which contains the common code.  Have this abstract class implement an interface which contains the necessary methods.

Have both other classes extend the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an interface with methods openDoor() and closeDoor(). After that inherit classes A and X from this interface and implement methods.
If methods implementation are similar then you can create utility class with static methods.

Comment: yes i had done the same thing, but still is this the best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface YourInterface{
  public void openDoor();
  public void closeDoor();
}

public abstract class YourAbstractClass implements YourInterface{
  public abstract void openDoor();
  public abstract void closeDoor();
}

public class YourClass extends YourAbstractClass{
  @Override
  public void openDoor();
  public void closeDoor();
}

public class YourSubClass extends YourClass{
  //you can just call super methods here
  super.openDoor();
  super.closeDoor();
}
```

Comment: you approach is good but if you extend some class , you cannot extend other classes. But in case of interface you can implement more than one interface.

Comment: its ok, since mr.user3114009 is only looking for a way to avoid duplication of methods

Comment: I believe that YourSubClass Class is the one he is looking for